# Adding more lines in geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting the number of Gasoline and EV vehicles with different vintages in each year. Each colour represents a vintage. When I use the actual dataset, the line between EV and Gasoline (the dotted line in the figure) becomes undetectable. How can I add another line separating EV from Gasoline cars for all vintages in all years?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = y, y = number/1000, color=Type, fill=as.factor(desc(v)))) + 
  geom_area(stat="identity", linetype = 2, size =0.1 ) +
  geom_text(data=df, aes(x=2029, y=20000, label="EV"),size=3, color="black") +
  geom_text(data=df, aes(x=2027, y=5000, label="Gasoline"),size=5, color="black") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Vintages")) +
  guides(colour=FALSE)
```

[image]

Here is part of the dataset:

```
df<- structure(list(v = c(2026, 2026, 2026, 2026, 2026, 2027, 2027, 
2027, 2027, 2027, 2028, 2028, 2028, 2028, 2028, 2029, 2029, 2029, 
2029, 2029, 2030, 2030, 2030, 2030, 2030, 2026, 2026, 2026, 2026, 
2026, 2027, 2027, 2027, 2027, 2027, 2028, 2028, 2028, 2028, 2028, 
2029, 2029, 2029, 2029, 2029, 2030, 2030, 2030, 2030, 2030), 
    y = c(2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 2030L, 2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 
    2029L, 2030L, 2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 2030L, 2026L, 2027L, 
    2028L, 2029L, 2030L, 2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 2030L, 2026L, 
    2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 2030L, 2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 2030L, 
    2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 2030L, 2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 
    2030L, 2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 2030L), Type = c("EV", 
    "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", 
    "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", 
    "EV", "EV", "EV", "EV", "gasoline", "gasoline", "gasoline", 
    "gasoline", "gasoline", "gasoline", "gasoline", "gasoline", 
    "gasoline", "gasoline", "gasoline", "gasoline", "gasoline", 
    "gasoline", "gasoline", "gasoline", "gasoline", "gasoline", 
    "gasoline", "gasoline", "gasoline", "gasoline", "gasoline", 
    "gasoline", "gasoline"), number = c(213189.865946421, 213189.71590565, 
    213188.440559102, 213181.213595325, 213150.498999277, 0, 
    332143.919406143, 332143.685646769, 332141.698692092, 332130.439282254, 
    0, 0, 501331.161638226, 501330.808806663, 501327.809738373, 
    0, 0, 0, 724999.720261116, 724999.210013989, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    994452.702960333, 2158367.51055841, 2158365.9915222, 2158353.07971449, 
    2158279.91280412, 2157968.95343502, 0, 2077292.93414104, 
    2077291.47216427, 2077279.0453617, 2077208.62681379, 0, 0, 
    1945136.30020633, 1945134.93124, 1945123.29502616, 0, 0, 
    0, 1756906.26442435, 1756905.02793232, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1521184.38412009
    )), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "y", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    c(0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 35L, 40L, 45L), c(1L, 
    6L, 11L, 16L, 21L, 26L, 31L, 36L, 41L, 46L), c(2L, 7L, 12L, 
    17L, 22L, 27L, 32L, 37L, 42L, 47L), c(3L, 8L, 13L, 18L, 23L, 
    28L, 33L, 38L, 43L, 48L), c(4L, 9L, 14L, 19L, 24L, 29L, 34L, 
    39L, 44L, 49L)), group_sizes = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), biggest_group_size = 10L, labels = structure(list(
    y = 2026:2030), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame", vars = "y", drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add a line by calculating the annual total of gasoline cars.
I also switch to `annotate` below that so that only one layer of text is written. In the original, it was printing the text once at the specified coordinates for each of all 50 rows in the data set.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df, aes(x = y, y = number/1000, color=Type, 
               fill=as.character(v) %>% fct_rev())) + 
geom_area(stat="identity", linetype = 2, size =0.1 ) +
geom_line(data = df %>% ungroup() %>% 
            filter(Type == "gasoline") %>% 
            count(y, wt = number/1000),  
          aes(x = y, y = n), inherit.aes = F,  
          color = "black", size = 0.5, lty = "dashed") +
annotate("text", x=2029, y=10000, label="EV" ,size=5, color="black") +
annotate("text", x=2028.5, y=5000, label="Gasoline",size=5, color="black") +
guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Vintages")) +
guides(colour=FALSE)
```

[image]